# Remove a track from a spotify playlist

Tags: spotify

I'm writing a Spotify app.  It generates a playlist of songs which appear onscreen using the default playlist view.  How can I allow the user to go in and delete songs from this list?  Selecting a track and pressing the delete button does not do it.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what you mean. Please share screenshots / code of what you are doing. Moreover, what is the "default playlist"? Do you mean the play queue? I have also written an application that edits playlists but do not have the problem you describe. Remember also to specify what API version you are using.

Giacecco